# Correlated coefficients in quantile regression model

Tags: regression, quantiles

I have a question in understanding the quantile regression model. Because the regression at different quantiles always uses all the samples. Would this lead to the correlation in different quantiles levels (e.g. 10% and 90%) results from the use of the same dataset to estimate all quantiles. Failing to addressing the correlation may lead to incorrect variance estimation including p-values, confidence intervals across quantile levels.

I have read through the publications from the author who 'invent' this approach. However, I didn't find the answer to my question. Any insights will be grateful. Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do, estimate differences between slopes at different quantiles, or something like that?  You could always use the bootstrap to estimate the standard error of such a difference.  This would account for the correlations, if you do the bootstrapping appropriately.

Comment: I performed F test as here http://fmwww.bc.edu/EC-C/S2016/8823/ECON8823.S2016.nn04.slides.pdf suggesetd to compare regression coefficient at different quantiles. However, I got a question as in the post, which I could not answer in a thoroughway. Becasue the quantile regression always use all the data to estimate coefficients, it makes people feel the correlation is inevitable.

Comment: This is a case of "read the manual."  I would guess they do it right if they took all the trouble to code it for general use, but you never know for sure.

Comment: why would you have a concern about "correlation in different quantiles levels" ? Sorry, just to be clear, the quantile is applied on your dependent variable, not your independent variable. If you set tau to be 0.5 you are doing a regression against the median.

Comment: So normally we would use 1 value for tau, for example 0.5, and you perform the regression. Where does the other problems come in?

Comment: I made the code in this link. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/513708/how-to-understand-the-coefficients-from-regression-at-different-quantiles-do-th, I was asked to explain if the coefficient of quantile regression at different quanitle correlated, because all the quantile regression always used the same full sample data. I think the question is from intuition, but I can not answer in a thorough way that the regressions at different quantiles are not correlated.

Comment: They are indeed correlated for the reason you mention - all based on the same data.

Comment: Is this a problem? Considering there is a large number of publications that applied this approach. How to prove the correlation is not an issue in the application?