# How to understand the coefficients from regression at different quantiles. Do they correlated with each other?

Tags: r, regression, quantile-regression

I applied quantile regression on this example data:

```
t<- data.frame(id=seq(1,100), measureX =rnorm(100,0,1),measureY = rnorm(100,0,2))
```

This is the code I used:

```
library(quantreg)
quantreg.all<- rq(measureY ~ measureX, tau = seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1), data=t)
quantreg.all
```

When I see the output, I feel not clear about this question: are the regression coefficients at different quantiles correlated? As the model always use all the data to estimate regression coefficients at different quantiles (e.g. 10% and 90%).
Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. I do expect to get some insights regarding the specific test for randomness of the quantile regression coefficients in r.

Comment: Thank you! I have added this question on CV.com, however, I didn't get a response.  Can you elaborate a little on "order statistics"? Do you suggest that the quantile regression estimation was made based on "order statistics" and the sample was order to make the estimation of coefficients. Therefore, the sample in the asymmetrically weighted absolute residuals of quantile regression has different weight, and the correlation is unlikely?  I am not sure if this understanding is correct.